# Number dividing the factorial of a lowest prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I would like to ask a probably simple question but I am not sure how to make it rigorous.

Let $p$ be a prime and $n$ a natural number whose lowest prime factor is $p$. If a natural number $x$ divides both $p!$ and $n$, is it true that $x=1$ or $p$?

I have no idea, but I am trying to say yes, and of course (if possible) elementarily without using named theorems except the fundamental theorem.

I am sure $x$ cannot be $2,3,...,p-1$ as it divides $n$, and also no prime factor of $x$ is lower than $p$. However, $x$ dividing $p!$ means that $x$ cannot have any prime factor greater than $p$ and also $x$ cannot be $p^k$ for every $k\geq 2$. Hence it is done by the fundamental theorem of arithmetics.

Is the above reasoning correct? Is something missing? And/or is something too much?

Thanks for the guide.

Comment: The reasoning is valid, though Saying that "x cannot be 2,3,..." is a slight distraction. What you really want is just the latter "no prime factor if x is strictly smaller than p".

Comment: If you replace "be $p^k$ for every ..." by "be $p^k$ for any ...", then the reasoning is perfectly valid. I would prefer this formulation because the current one might be misunderstood. Even better would be mentioning that $p^2\mid p!$ is impossible , hence $x=p^k$ with $k\ge 2$ is impossible.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for all the inputs! I can improve from that. This actually appears in Hungerford algebra book section group action.